# Jenkins: store build information for later reference

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to store custom information, for example my staging environment ID. I need this information for cleanup purposes later after the staging environment is no longer needed.

Ideally, I want a database table where I have these columns, `buildName`, `buildCommit`, `pullRequest`.

Then when the pull request is closed/merged I can simply find all `buildName`s and `buildCommits`
for that pull request and remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a database, you can always shell out to a database:

```
sh "mysql -u my_username -p my_password -h my_hostname -P 3306 -e \'INSERT INTO my_table (column1, column2, ...) VALUES (value1, value3, ...);\'  my_database"
```

You can also write out your data to a JSON or YAML or whatever type of file and then store it in Jenkins' built-in artifact storage with [archiveArtifacts](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/#archiveartifacts-archive-the-artifacts).

Comment: how can i use this with postgres database installed in same server of jenkis ?